# How can I override the price string for WooCommerce Subscriptions only for a specific product?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have this code and I would like to apply it only for a specific product. What would be those extra lines of code for that? Thank you!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string_inclusions', 'wpd_override_subscription_price_string', 10, 2 );
function wpd_override_subscription_price_string( $include, $product ) {
  
    /*
 
        'tax_calculation'     => get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_shop' ),
        'subscription_price'  => true,
        'subscription_period' => true,
        'subscription_length' => true,
        'sign_up_fee'         => true,
        'trial_length'        => true,
 
    */
 
    $include['subscription_period'] = false;
    $include['sign_up_fee'] = false;
    $include['trial_length'] = false;
 
    return $include;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit by product ID you can do like this

```
function wpd_override_subscription_price_string( $include, $product ) {

    if($product->get_id() !== '1234'){
        return $include;
    }

    $include['subscription_period'] = false;
    $include['sign_up_fee'] = false;
    $include['trial_length'] = false;
 
    return $include;
 
}
```

Cahnge 1234 to your product ID